# Openshift K8s cluster CPU and memory metrics issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, openshift, amazon-eks

We have an AWS hosted openshift cluster running, at the moment we have 10 worker nodes and 3 control planes. We are using new relic as the monitoring platform. Our problem is as follows. Overall cluster resources are low, that is

1. CPU usage - average 25%
2. Memory usage - 37%.

But under load, the metrics shows some nodes are fully occupied and are at max CPU and memory usage while others are not and still overall cluster resource usage is low

We have a feeling that we have too much compute resources over provisioned. We have actually noted the same using **AWS compute optimizer**

How do we make the cluster resource utilization to be optimal like overall utilization of above 70% .

Why are some worker nodes being utilized to the maximum while others are seriously under utilized.

Any links to k8s cluster optimization will be appreciated

Using node toleration to assign some workloads to certain worker nodes

Comment: I think that this isn't the right place to ask this. StackExchange has a DevOps forum that may be more appropriate. SO is more about programming. Having said that, as a senior architect, I'd start by asking why you're using openshift rather than EKS. Given that you're in AWS EKS makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I agree with the comment that StackOverflow isn't really the place for this. But the real issue here is that you don't provide information on your workloads. You say that you are using node toleration to assign some workloads to certain worker nodes. That is almost certainly related to the problem. Use OpenShift's monitoring to look at the busy nodes, figure out which pods are consuming all of the resources. The scheduler will automatically balance the workloads as long as you provide it with the information it needs (cpu/mem requests) and within the constraints you provide (like taints).

Comment: I am agree with the previous comment